# DB2 display number in integer form

Tags: sql, db2

I am doing an assignment for a course and have a table of sales which contains a field for paid_amt as double (to reduce confusion from dealing with money in cents).

The problem is that when I do a command:

```
select paid_amt from sales
```

it displays

```
PAID_AMT
------------------------
  +2.00000000000000E+002
  +3.33000000000000E+002
```

I want it to display

```
PAID_AMT
------------------------
200
333
```

instead.

How would I do this?

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT CAST(paid_amt AS INTEGER) FROM sales` ?

Comment: Why is Decimal or Numeric "confusing"?  And displaying 333 to a user, instead of $3.33, would not be confusing to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For db2

```
SELECT INTEGER(paid_amt)
from sales
```

For Sql

```
SELECT CAST(paid_amt AS INT)
from sales
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
CAST(PAID_AMT AS INT)
```